# How to Write a Function for WebElement Click in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am Having a Lot of WebElements
For Example I Declared a WebElement a

```
@FindBy(id="BtnLogin")
private WebElement btnLogin;
```

In the Same Manner I created "N" number of WebElements
Every time I Cant use "driver.findElement()" function So I wrote a function

```
public static void WebElementClick(WebElement we)
{
we.click();
}
```

When Ever the Control is Going to The Line we.click() in the WebElementclick Function it is Showing NullPointerException as a Result My Purpose is Failing

I am Not Getting What to Do,Some One Please Help Me on this :)

Comment: It is possible that your page is changed/reloaded before you click the element.Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573231/i-am-getting-nullpointer-exception-when-i-perform-click-for-the-same-webelemen

Comment: Hi,No I am on Login page and there is No Question of page getting Reloaded because What i Do Enter Userid,Password and click on login Button

Answer (score 0):

Your `WebElementClick` should receive the selector and it should: find element -> click, you can get an example from the above link.

In your case you it seems that you are not using wait and the `WebElementClick` it tries to click on the string.
Using find will return an object that will make click available.

The method should contain something like: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_selector"));` 
Ant then use click on what this method returns.You can use also css if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class testJava{
@Test
public void testMethod() throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    pageClass pageClass = PageFactory.initElements(driver, pageClass.class);
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    pageClass.clickLoginBtn();
}}

public class pageClass {
@FindBy(id = "loginbutton")
 private WebElement loginBtn;

WebDriver driver;
public pageClass(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
public void clickLoginBtn()
{
    click(loginBtn);
}

public void click(WebElement we)
{
    we.click();
}}
```

Its best practice to use the page class & test class..Try this it will help you i guess.
You are suppose to use driver to find & click the element.

Answer (score 0):

I think that driver may try to click element before it's presented. Good practice before clicking WebElement is to wait for WebElement being clickable. I would try:

```
public static void WebElementClick(WebElement we)
{
    wait.forElementClickable(we);
    we.click();
}
```